# how to display image in html using jsp call?

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart

I m trying to display an image in html page calling a jsp page in `<img />` tag as follows.
I have created dynamic web project, have added `index.html` under webcontent folder, `timeseries.jsp` under `webcontent` → `jsp` folder.
When I run the project on server, adding apache tomcat 6.0.18, its synchronised, but when I enter url `localhost:8080/jfree` it displays only hello doctor and image icon on the page but no image there.

My HTML is,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello doctor
<img src="/jfree/jsp/Timeseries.jsp" alt="Progress chart" />
</body>
</html>
```

My JSP is,

```jsp
<%@ page import="java.awt.Image" %>
<%@ page import="java.awt.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@ page import="java.awt.BasicStroke"%>
<%@ page import ="org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.axis.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.entity.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.labels.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.urls.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.category.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.general.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.time.Minute"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.time.Hour"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.StandardXYItemRenderer"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import=java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>

<%@ page import="java.awt.image.BufferedImage"%>
<%
try
{
    File image = File.createTempFile("image", "tmp");

    //chart class instance
    Fms fm = new Fms("Graph");

    JFreeChart chart = fm.createChart(fm.dataset);
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(image, chart, 500, 400);
    //get input stream
    FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(image);
    //output stream foe returning chart as image
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream(); 
    long fileLength;
    byte[] byteStream;
    fileLength = image.length();
    byteStream = new byte[(int)fileLength];
    //read chart image
    fileInStream.read(byteStream, 0, (int)fileLength);
    //returns chart image whenever called
    response.setContentType("image/png");
    response.setContentLength((int)fileLength);
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store,no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    fileInStream.close();
    outStream.write(byteStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.err.println("Problem occurred creating chart.");
}
%>
<%!
public class Fms extends ApplicationFrame {
    //Main class
    XYDataset dataset= null;
    public Fms(final String title) {
        super(title);
        dataset= createDataset();
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 570));
        chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true, false);
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    } 
    //chart creation method
    JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                                    "Speed Chart",
                                    "Time",
                                    "Speed",
                                    dataset,
                                    true,
                                    true,
                                    false
                                    );
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(false);
        final XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();

        if (renderer instanceof StandardXYItemRenderer) {
            final StandardXYItemRenderer rr = (StandardXYItemRenderer) renderer;
            rr.setShapesFilled(true);
            renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.0f));
            renderer.setSeriesStroke(1, new BasicStroke(1.0f));
        }    
        final DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM")); 
        try{
            final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo
            (new StandardEntityCollection());
            final File file1 = new File("c:/Documents and Settings/accounts/WebApplication2/web/barchart.png");
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
        }catch(Exception e){ }

        return chart;
    }
    //data set generation method
    private XYDataset createDataset() {

        final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.setDomainIsPointsInTime(true);

        final TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Series 1", Minute.class);
        s1.add(new Minute(0, 0, 7, 7, 2003), 10.2);
        s1.add(new Minute(30, 12, 7, 8, 2003), 23.0);
        s1.add(new Minute(15, 14, 7, 9, 2003), 48.0);

        final TimeSeries s2 = new TimeSeries("Series 2", Minute.class);
        s2.add(new Minute(0, 0, 7, 7, 2003), 23.0);
        s2.add(new Minute(30, 12, 7, 8, 2003), 9.0);
        s2.add(new Minute(15, 14, 7, 9, 2003), 36.0);

        dataset.addSeries(s1);
        dataset.addSeries(s2);

        return dataset;
    }
}
%>
```

but its not dispaying the image in jsp? any help?

Comment: You really need to stop here and learn about the capabilities of JSP. Note that serving an image is not the task of JSP but of a Servlet.

Comment: i got the code from here, http://jspimageupload.blogspot.in/2010/11/create-and-display-dynamic-chart-in-jsp.html

Comment: they say jsp returns an image

Comment: Well, they are **wrong**. When you execute the GET method on the JSP you will get a `text/html` response, when you want/need a `image/jpeg` (or `png` or whatever the extension of your image is) response. You can't change the response type directly in a JSP but you can do this in a Servlet. Note that since you will retrieve the image in a GET, you must move all these scriptlets into a Servlet, inside the `doGet` method.

Comment: I have also used `jfreechart`, but I have not saved images on the server instead created byte array & send through response. Drawback in image saving is that you need to delete that image after it's work is over, also memory space.

Answer (score 1):

This **is** possible, and it's also pretty simple. And you **can** set the response type of your JSP page with the following tag:

```
<%@page contentType="image/png" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Furthermore, there's no need to save these charts to the server's file system. They can be written directly to the response's output stream using the ImageIO class. Here's an example JSP page which I've named `Chart.jsp`:

```
<%@page import="javax.imageio.*"%>
<%@page import="org.jfree.data.xy.*"%>
<%@page import="org.jfree.chart.*"%>
<%@page import="java.awt.image.*"%>
<%@page contentType="image/png" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    DefaultXYDataset data = new DefaultXYDataset();
    data.addSeries("Set 1", new double[][] {
        {1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7}, 
        {0, 10, 20, 30, 20, 10}
    });
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Title", "X Label", "Y Label", data);
    BufferedImage bi = chart.createBufferedImage(640, 480);
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", response.getOutputStream());
%>
```

And here's `index.html` which refers to it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>body { text-align: center; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>A Chart:</h1>
        <img src="Chart.jsp" alt="Chart" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the result:

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 0):

First this statement would not work: `<img src="/jfree/jsp/Timeseries.jsp" alt="Progress chart" />`

I guess here your thought process is that the JSP would return an image and you could display the image in html `<img ...` tag. Well this is *not* like a method call where something is responded back to the caller.

For your HTML, when it will load, it would try to locate a file with `/jfree/jsp/Timeseries.jsp` assuming that this file is a image format file like jpeg, bmp etc. **It will actually not going to execute any JSP call on the server.**

Since this file is simple ascii file containing some bytes(even though a valid jsp code, but not an image bytes); the bytes does not actually represent any image. So HTML is not working.

Edit 1:
Whatever you want to accomplish could be done like this:

> 1. Create a servlet, which will build the image at runtime, and then save that on a server location.
> 2. Test this application and see, if the servlet is creating the image file at a server location say /apps/html/images/yourImage.jpg.
> 3. Make sure that the image location is a location where html has access. For the timebeing generate the image in the same directory as
>      of HTML.
> 4. Once your image is producing and you could open the image using a image editor, set the same image name(with relative location) in the
>      HTML.
> 5. Edit the servlet code to add a redirect code, such that the servlet redirect you to the html page.
> 6. Since by the time HTML is loaded, the  image is already present, your HTML should work fine.

I hope these step would achieve your goal.

Comment: how to convert these bytes to image? any way?

Comment: I have edited the post to narrate a possible solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, You are creating a chart image using `JfreeChart` and wanna display this chart image on one of your JSP ? 
Recently I worked with `JFreeChart` library to create lots of charts for case study and analysis for a website users.
If this is the requirement try below things:

1. Create chart and save as png to any folder inside web-root folder of
   your web-application. (If needed store the names of created images
   in db accordingly)
2. In your jsp use image tag and simply provide path upto your required
   image with name of image including your context path.

**Edit :**  Below lines in your code will automatically save your chart into a png image. So no need to worry about saving your images . just give the proper path, where you have to save chart as image. Give me 20 min I will keep entire code.

```
JFreeChart chart = fm.createChart(fm.dataset);
 ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(image, chart, 500, 400);
```

**Edit 2 :** Suppose in your application's web-root folder you have a folder name "Images"
Now below piece of code will give the path upto my Images folder(Including context path of my application) and if that "chart_folder" is not available inside "Images" it will create a new one with this name:

```
 //Get the servers upload directory real path name
                        String filePath = req.getRealPath("/Images");

                        //create the chart_folder folder if do not exists...
                        File folder = new File(filePath);
                        if(!folder.exists())
                         {
                           folder.mkdir();
                         }
```

Now with below code I will use this path to save my chart image with required name and will keep the entire path with chart image name in request attribute to get it on my JSP page(You can do according to your requirement i.e. use `ServletContext.getContextPath()+"/Images/chart_folder"+<your image name her>` etc..):

```
  path=filePath+"/chart_folder";
 ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File(path +"/chart3.png"), chart ,no, 400);
                         filePath= path+"\\chart3.png";
                         req.setAttribute("graph_path3",filePath);
```

Now in your JSP you can get this entire path with image name to use in  tag to display your image.

For any further query feel free to ping.

Comment: yes u got my problem correctly sir..but im struggling about how to convert my jfreechart to image..:(

Comment: No need of doing any extra stuffs. I am editing my answer and trying to pin point to your problem. I f you need any code just ask me.

Comment: i need a simple code which crates a xy plotter jfreechart and then converts it to image, my code is as above, but it isnt working

Comment: I answered a similar question here. Have a look on this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204745/jfreechart-bar-chart-production/#17205022

If still it dont solves your problem, you are welcome for any further query.

Comment: ok sir i understand the line ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File(filePath +"/chart1.png"), chart ,1250, 400); is used to actually conver the chart to png, but wats filepath here, is it possible to edit my code for u to generate png? or can u direct me to as n where i can use saveChartaspng() method in my code?

Comment: ok i understand its about editing the path for image, wat can be the way to edit the path?

Comment: sure sir, im trying hands on ur suggestions if i require help i come here..:)

Comment: Sure saumyachauhan35@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

May be error is occurring in below line.

```
FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(image);
```

First check image exists or not by using `image.exist()`. Because it is working fine for static image, then we will move forward.